# How to ensure one-many relationship in graph databases?

Tags: foreign-keys, graph-databases

In RDBMS, we use foreign key to ensure one-many relationship. For example, we will ensure one employee only belong to one department.

In graph databases, how can we ensure this?

Comment: Their are several different ways you can do this but it is highly dependent on the database you are using.  Which graph DB are you using?

Comment: I am using Neo4j.